# Filter_input false, $_POST has data

Tags: php

so I have a issue that I cannot shake, I am confident I am doing something simple wrong, but none the less I cannot find the mistake, I have a html select element with 2 option elements, the select is set to multiple and both options are set for selected, all you have to do is click the Apply button and see what the result is.

So my issue is this, when you run this scenario and do a variable dump on filter input, it returns false(no data), but when you variable dump the $_POST global it has the data I am looking for, any idea what i am doing wrong.

here is the code:

```
$submit = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'submit', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);

if(!isset($submit)){
    ?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <select name="partsused[]" id="usedparts" multiple>
        <option value="empty" selected>Empty</option>
        <option value="full" selected>Full</option>
    </select>

    <br/>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Apply</button>
</form>
  <?php  
} else {    
    $someArray = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'partsused');

    var_dump($someArray);
    var_dump($_POST['partsused']);
    die;
}
```

The output I get from the var_dump is as follows :

```
bool(false) 
array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "empty" [1]=> string(4) "full" }
```

So as you can see the filter_input does not read the value at all from the $_POST as it should, I have tried all the different filters even not filtering at all.

so just to make this clear, yes assigning the S_POST['partsused'] to the variable $someArray does then work, but I dont like doing that, I always use filter_input, not sure why this is doing this, any ideas or takes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php#115960) comment, if the input is an array and you are using `filter_input`, you need to use the following setup:

```
var_dump(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'partsused', FILTER_DEFAULT , FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY));
```

and as per the documentation:

> `FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY` - Requires the value to be an array.

Comment: So thanks, this works as I see now, but my question is this, I have used it this way before on Checkboxes grouped, and I also use the filter_require_array, tried that by the way, but the difference is that you have filter_default as well, why is that solving the issue, as I understand the filter_require_array is all that should have been used, but filter_default solves the issue, can you maybe explain why filter_default works, as I understand the filter_default, says don't filter it.

Comment: @Ronald don't quote me on this but from what I can see based on the documentation is that `FILTER_DEFAULT` is a sanitize flag whereas `FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY` is a standard options flag. Secondly, both the 3rd and 4th parameters in the function are optional so to set the 4th parameter we need to provide `FILTER_DEFAULT` which is also the optional value if the 3rd parameter is omitted. Again, take this with a pinch of salt as I'm no expert in the inner workings of `filter_input`.

Answer (score 0):

You must use [filter_input_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input-array.php) instead

```
$someArray = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, 'partsused');
```